# Would an Asus GPU work on an HP Motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, compatibility, nvidia-geforce

I'm planning on buying the Asus GeForce GTX 1650 O4G-LP-BRK (or GeForce GTX1650LP for short) and installing it in an HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF. I've replaced the 240W PSU with a 300W PSU, and I was wondering if the Asus GeForce GTX1650 LP would be compatible with the motherboard, considering the motherboard has a PCI-E x16 slot for another graphics card, and I've seen multiple videos on YouTube where the Zotac GeForce GTX1650 LP worked even with the standard 240W PSU.

I was wondering if there are any major differences between the Asus and Zotac Graphic cards, i.e. the Asus GPU is incompatible with non Asus motherboards?

Would really appreciate if I could get an answer as I'm still running on the quite terrible integrated Intel HD 4600 GPU.